# analysis crash dump created by gflags.exe of .net 4.0 but there was no enough information

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps, sos

a windows service written in c# 4.0, setting gflags.exe(Global Flags) to save the dump when process crashing.

But when I open the crash dump in windbg, I got the 0:00> . I am not good at windbg, and I remembered Tess's blog said when opening a crash dump you should see the threads id which the exception occurs, but what I see is 0:00>... and !pe has no useful result.

using !dumpheap -stat, I could only see few objects, so how can I analysis this dump?
thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: `!pe` will only give you the exception on the current thread, so you may need to switch to another thread in order to dump the exception. Use `!threads` to get an overview of the managed threads. This will also list any managed exceptions for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you see few objects using !dumpheap -stat, then it is likely that this dump was generated too late, or at a wrong time.

You may try to use Debug Diag or ADPlus to recapture the dump (of course you need to reset the changes in GFlags before doing that).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lexli/archive/2009/08/23/when-the-application-program-crashes-on-windows.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does **~*e !pe** output an exception of your interest?
The long way is:

```
!threads
~#s, where # is the number of the thread which has an exception
!pe
```